# Cannot create mysql database, using jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So here is the code:

```
**package com.install.main;

import java.sql.*;

public class Executor {

   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "eli";
   static final String PASS = null;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try{
          //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

          //STEP 3: Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

          //STEP 4: Execute a query
          System.out.println("Creating database... ");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();

          System.out.println("Connection: " + conn);

          String sql = "CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS";
          stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
          System.out.println("Database created successfully... ");
       }catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
          //finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }// nothing we can do
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }//end finally try
       }//end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
}//end JDBCExample**
```

And here is the output:

```
Connecting to database...
Creating database... 
Connection: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@5e265ba4
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'STUDENTS'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2605)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1469)
    at com.install.main.Executor.main(Executor.java:34)
Goodbye!
```

Does anyone of you happen to know why it tries to connect to database I have just created and why does it actually not create database? I have not set any password for mysql.

If I execute thisstatement:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'eli'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eli' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

in MySQL Wrokbench, I also get the same error, saying:

```
05:43:15 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'eli'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eli' WITH GRANT OPTION Error Code: 1045.
```

The think is if I type mysql command in my console - it logs me in as `eli@localhost` without giving any user name or password... I am on Ubuntu - this refers to my username on computer but the error is still there - and I cannot do anything.

If do this `mysql> select * from information_schema.user_privileges;` on command line:

this is what I can see:

`+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE        | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE | IS_GRANTABLE |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| ''@'localhost' | def           | USAGE          | NO           |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

... But if I do this `select user();`:

`+---------------+
| user()        |
+---------------+
| eli@localhost |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

I tried using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` but it never asked me to enter a new password - just restarted my server, that was all.

Sorry, but what is going on here?

Comment: `user ''@'localhost'` seems like `USER` isn't holding the value you think it is ("eli")

Comment: @TylerSebastian No, more likely that `'eli'@'localhost'` does not exist on the MySQL server so he is getting logged in as `''@'localhost'` (any_user [at] localhost).

Comment: If I execute thisstatement: "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'eli'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eli' WITH GRANT OPTION;" in MySQL Wrokbench, I also get the same error, saying: "05:43:15 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'eli'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eli' WITH GRANT OPTION Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user ''@'localhost'"

Comment: Think is if I type mysql command in my console - it logs me in as `eli@localhost` without giving any user name or password... I am on Ubuntu - this refers to my username on computer but the error is still there - and I cannot do anything.

Comment: I tried using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` but it never asked me to enter a new password - just restarted my server, that was all.

Comment: `SELECT USER()` simply echoes the user/host combination passed by the client to the server. To see the *effective* ("authenticated") user/host combination that is in effect for the session you need to use `SELECT CURRENT_USER()`. What does that show you?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is clearly defined in this output

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'STUDENTS'
```

You have declared user for database 'eli'

```
static final String USER = "eli";
```

but in the output you can see that the user is not set for this database, and one reason i can see straight away is that you are not actually pointing to your database at all.

What you should have is

```
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/STUDENTS";
```

Comment: If I execute thisstatement: 

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'eli'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eli' WITH GRANT OPTION;` 

in MySQL Wrokbench, I also get the same error, saying: 

    `05:43:15 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'eli'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eli' WITH GRANT OPTION Error Code: 1045. `

Comment: Think is if I type mysql command in my console - it logs me in as `eli@localhost` without giving any user name or password... I am on Ubuntu - this refers to my username on computer.

Comment: I tried using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` but it never asked me to enter a new password - just restarted my server, that was all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't created a user named `eli` for the host `localhost` (`'eli'@'localhost'`), so MySQL is logging you in as `''@'localhost'` (any_user [at] localhost) and that user does not have CREATE privileges on the MySQL server.

So, create a user in MySQL for `'eli'@'localhost'` (*not* `'eli'@'%'`) and grant that user CREATE privileges.

Comment: Think is if I type mysql command in y console - it logs me in as `eli@localhost` without giving any user name or password... I am on Ubuntu - this refers to my username on computer but the error is still there - and I cannot do anything.

Comment: I tried using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` but it never asked me to enter a new password - just restarted my server, that was all.